# TypeError: Fields.flat is not a function (node.js already updated)

Tags: discord.js

I’ve seen a few topics related to this before with the solution of updating to the latest version of NPM. I’ve tried that already and now it says version 15.3.0 when I run node -v.

[Screenshot of Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9m77.png)

Comment: Please paste a text version of the logs instead of a picture

Comment: Too long to paste out so I uploaded it to pastebin. https://pastebin.com/K45B9UrM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old thread but giving the solution anyway :

I've got the same error, the solution was to completely uninstall Node and npm

```
sudo apt-get remove nodejs
sudo apt-get remove npm
```

try to do

```
node -v
```

If you get a result just do

```
which node
```

then delete the folder

```
rm -r *previous_result*
```

To be sure of removing everything do

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/npm 
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/man/man1/node* 
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d
rm -rf ~/.npm
rm -rf ~/.node-gyp
sudo rm -rf /opt/local/bin/node
sudo rm -rf /opt/local/include/node
sudo rm -rf /opt/local/lib/node_modules
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node*
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/include/node*
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/node*
```

I did this and my problem got solved.